# Plot dates matlab

Tags: matlab, date, time, plot

I've a matrix called datevector containing the year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds of the timeseries that I would like to plot.

```
datevector = [...
2009    11  4   11  35  0
2009    11  4   11  36  0
2009    11  4   11  37  0
2009    11  4   11  38  0
2009    11  4   11  39  0
2009    11  4   11  40  0]
```

To plot my data with respect to this time series I create the array containing the time series

```
xdate = datenum(datevector);
```

and then I try to plot my `data = [1 2 3 4 5 6]`

```
figure
plot(xdate',data)
datetick('x','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS')
```

...well the figure I get is not the one expected...I would like to have a minute resolution as in datavector...can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to use the `'keepticks'` option with `datetick`.